# SELECT em PHP só retorna a partir do segundo INSERT do mesmo usuário

Tags: php

**O resultado do seguinte SELECT**

```
    <?php
         include_once("conect.php");
         $id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
         $result_usuario = "SELECT * FROM produ_usu WHERE id = '$id'";
         $resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);
         $row_usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuario);

          if(($resultado_usuario) AND ($resultado_usuario->num_rows != 0)){
               while($row_usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuario)){
     ?>
```

só retorna dados a partir do segundo INSERT com mesmo id (id do usuário).

Eu sei que o problema é causado pela linha

```
$row_usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuario);
```

logo abaixo da linha

```
$resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);
```

Comento a linha e o SELECT retorna após o primeiro INSERT de um usuário com seu id normalmente.

Resumindo, não entendi o porque com a famigerada linha só retorna a partir do segundo `insert`

A pergunta é: porque com essa linha retorna somente após o segundo insert do mesmo id?

Comment: Já deu um var_dump($row_usuario); pra certificar que todos os dados estão vindo corretamente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `mysqli` usa um cursor pra controlar os itens que você recupera através do `mysqli_fetch_assoc` que avança 1 item a cada ve que ele é chamado,  e como você já deu um `mysqli_fetch_assoc` lá em `$row_usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuario);` , o teu while tá iniciando no item seguinte.

Isso é melhor explicado na doc do php https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: Putz, eu vi que só retornava quando num_rows era 2, o que indicaria exatamente o que você acabou de responder. Parabéns pelo clareza da sua visão. Vou consultar meu oculista :-)

Comment: Disponha. Deixar algum detalhe passar é algo que até mesmo o mais experiente desenvolvedor deixa acontecer ^^

Comment: É verdade, mas tem gente ai negativando minha pergunta, não sabe contribuir mas  sabe negativar, tenho pena.